# GIS SE policy on AI-generated content

Tags: support, faq, answers

There is a new AI chatbot called ChatGPT by OpenAI. It appears to be able to answer questions and generate code based on what you ask it.

What's our policy on AI-generated content in GIS SE?

Answer (score 9):

At this time, I think our default position on this should be the same as that adopted by Stack Overflow at [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).

The background to that policy is explained in their Help Center as [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).